# Spark streaming 1.6.0 - Executors bouncing

Tags: apache-spark

We are using Spark Streaming 1.6.0 running on AWS EMR 4.3.x, consuming data from a Kinesis stream.
Used to work properly in Spark 1.3.1
After migration, we are unable to withstand the load for long.
Ganglia shows that the cluster's used memory keeps growing till some limit is reached without a GC.
After that there are several really long micro-batches (in terms of dozens of minutes instead of several seconds).
And then Spark starts killing and bouncing executors (done over and over),

Basically the cluster becomes unusable.
The problem is reproducible under load, time after time.
What could be the reason for Spark failing to GC without killing executors?
How can we make the cluster run for weeks (currently cannot make it run for hours)

Any input is welcome.

We are using the following definitions when defining a job:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles", "true");
sparkConf.set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.5");
sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true");
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
```

Doing a union of

```
KinesisUtils.createStream(streamingContext, appName,
                        kinesisStreamName, kinesisEndpoint, awsRegionName, initialPositionInStream, checkpointInterval,
                        StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2());
```

I've stripped our application to a bare skeleton for the tests.
Kept map from byte stream to String stream, then convert to objects, filter out irrelevant events, then persist and store to S3.

eventStream = eventStream.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2());

eventStream = eventStream.repartition(configuration.getSparkOutputPartitions());
eventStream.foreachRDD(new RddByPartitionSaverFunction<>(new OutputToS3Function()));

Spark job is submitted with the following configuration (copied with memory size modification from the default Spark config):

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M 
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Adding exceptions.
1-st cluster

```
16/03/06 13:54:52 WARN BlockManagerMaster: Failed to remove broadcast 1327 with removeFromMaster = true - Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:185)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at org.spark-project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:133)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(Future.scala:643)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Future.scala:658)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Future.scala:635)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Future.scala:635)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch.run(Future.scala:634)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.scala$concurrent$Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$$unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:694)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:685)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:241)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:242)
        ... 7 more
16/03/06 13:54:52 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error cleaning broadcast 1327
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeBroadcast(BlockManagerMaster.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.unpersist(TorrentBroadcast.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.unbroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.unbroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.doCleanupBroadcast(ContextCleaner.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:180)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1180)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$3.run(ContextCleaner.scala:68)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        ... 12 more

16/03/06 13:55:04 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 6 on ip-***-194.ec2.internal: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 11.3 GB of 11.3 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
1
16/03/06 13:55:10 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 1 on ip-***-193.ec2.internal: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 11.3 GB of 11.3 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

Second cluster attempt:

```
16/03/07 14:24:38 ERROR server.TransportChannelHandler: Connection to ip-***-22.ec2.internal/N.N.N.22:40791 has been quiet for 120000 ms while there are outstanding requests. Assuming connection is dead; please adjust spark.network.timeout if this is wrong.
16/03/07 14:24:38 ERROR client.TransportResponseHandler: Still have 12 requests outstanding when connection from ip-***-22.ec2.internal/N.N.N.22:40791 is closed
16/03/07 14:24:38 ERROR netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Error while uploading block input-47-1457357970366
java.io.IOException: Connection from ip-***-22.ec2.internal/N.N.N.22:40791 closed
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/03/07 14:24:38 ERROR netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Error while uploading block input-15-1457357969730
java.io.IOException: Connection from ip-***-22.ec2.internal/N.N.N.22:40791 closed
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        a.io.IOException: Connection from ip-***-22.ec2.internal/N.N.N.22:40791 closed
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
t io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you find a solution or the problem?

Comment: Hi. 
No, we still haven't found a solution. 
The problem is reproducible only with a large number of Kinesis shards (120).
ONly then the executors start bouncing.
Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Executor bouncing stopped in Spark 2.0.0 (EMR 5.0.0). Got a new problem preventing a long run of the same application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289345/spark-streaming-2-0-0-freezes-after-several-days-under-load

Answer (score -2):

I do get something in the same vein..  When a micro batch took more than 120 seconds to complete, it fired:

```
16/03/14 22:57:30 INFO SparkStreaming$: Batch size: 2500, total read: 4287800
16/03/14 22:57:35 INFO SparkStreaming$: Batch size: 2500, total read: 4290300
16/03/14 22:57:42 INFO SparkStreaming$: Batch size: 2500, total read: 4292800
16/03/14 22:57:45 INFO SparkStreaming$: Batch size: 2500, total read: 4295300
16/03/14 22:59:45 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error cleaning broadcast 11251
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeBroadcast(BlockManagerMaster.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.unpersist(TorrentBroadcast.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.unbroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.unbroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.doCleanupBroadcast(ContextCleaner.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:180)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1180)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$3.run(ContextCleaner.scala:68)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        ... 12 more
```

I'm running in local mode and consuming from Kinesis.  I'm not using any broadcast variables either.