# Spark streaming 2.0.0 - freezes after several days under load

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We are running on AWS EMR 5.0.0 with Spark 2.0.0.
Consuming from a 125 shard Kinesis stream.
Feeding 19k events/s using 2 message producers, each message about 1k in size.
Consuming using a cluster of 20 machines.
The code has a flatMap(), groupByKey(), persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2()) and 
repartition(19);
Then storing to s3 using foreachRDD();
Using backpressure and Kryo:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true");
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
```

While running, Ganglia show a consistent increase in used memory without a GC.
At some point, when there's no more free memory to allocate, Spark stops processing micro batches and the incoming queue is growing.
That's the freeze point - spark streaming is not able to recover.
In our case, Spark froze after 3.5 days of running under pressure.

The problem: we need streaming to run for at least a week (preferably more) without restarting.

Spark cofiguration:

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' 
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dspark.driver.log.level=INFO -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' 
spark.master yarn-cluster
spark.executor.instances 19
spark.executor.cores 7
spark.executor.memory 7500M
spark.driver.memory 7500M
spark.default.parallelism 133
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 2950
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead 2950
spark.eventLog.enabled false
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs:///spark-logs/
```

Thanks in advance.